# Halachic status of Israeli airspace and waters

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory

I am presenting this hypothetical not because I want a ruling but because I want to understand the halachic mechanism involved and I'm wording the case specifically to avoid certain answers (so please do not dismiss this because the fact pattern seems outlandish). I am basing myself on certain opinions listed in [this](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/14627) site, as simplified by a person I spoke with about visiting Israel and returning to the US and I am NOT talking about one davening for the amud - just one davening silently.

I have won a ride in a blimp which will be taking off from Cairo and covering a soccer match in Tel Aviv so I fly from the US to Egypt and situate myself in the blimp.

The blimp flies over Israel during the zman when I need to daven mincha. Today's date is Oct 13 (Cheshvan 7). I, as a citizen of Chu"L would normally say "v'tein b'racha" in my amida but my flight path takes me OVER Israel where people are already saying "v'tein tal umatar b'racha". I am over Israel for an hour but never lands. Does the airspace create my "being" there so I would change what I say? What if I daven mincha before we leave so during my time over Israel, I do NOT daven, nor do I have to. Would my actual davening or not affect what I say when I return to Cairo and then the US?

If I travel by boat (not everyone gets to ride in the blimp) am I judged as being "in" Israel when I cross from international waters in to Israeli sovereign waters, when we reach port, dock, or when I actually step on Israeli land?

Comment: Even if he is in Israel, on land, and davens there all 3 tefillos, many poskim say he should continue saying Vsein Bracha since that is what is is said in his hometown where his livelihood is based. However, he may say vsein tal umatar in Shomeya Tefilla.

Comment: Flower pot with a hole in it hanging from the blimp

Comment: @Chatzkel I am taking, from the linked article, the opinion that says that he says "According to Birkei Yosef, if he is in Eretz Yisroel on the Seventh of MarCheshvan he should begin to recite ve’sein tal umatar then since he now has a need for rain; he should continue to recite this prayer even when he returns to chutz la’aretz. "

Comment: This is not a good example since there's little reason to think Halachic Israel is the defining factor for rain requests (and there's a thousand variations of how to handle travelers that complicates everything more). The classic case for this kind of question is better: suppose you have a flower pot on your boat; when do shmita/maaser rules apply to its fruit?

Comment: @Heshy Oh no please don't talk to me about perforated flowerpots, I have PTSD from all those halachos :p